# Praw: How to filter search results based on created date?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I want to have a script running in the background which will fetch subreddit data every hour or so. Now since I don't want duplicate entries in my db, I want to filter my search results based on created_utc

This is what I have currently:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='soc')
submissions = r.get_subreddit('soccer').get_hot()
```

And this is what I want to have:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='soc')
submissions = r.get_subreddit('soccer').get_hot(created_utc > '2016-02-18 14:33:14.000')
```

What are the ways to achieve this?

Comment: Do you actually want the hottest listings, or the newest listings? The hottest varies considerably and doesn't make much sense to try to filter based on datetime, since your own app's data might be stale by the time you run your next query.

Comment: @DanGayle does api have a get_new() function like there is get_hot()? I thought these two were similar

Comment: Yes, there is a get_new function. A subreddit's "hot" listing is an algorithmicly created list based on upvotes, time and I think a few other criteria. That list is always changing. The "new" listing is a reverse datetime sorted list, which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither the [`SubReddit` class](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/objects.py#L1427) nor the [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_hot) have the date-based filter methods that you want, so here is one option for you:

Filter the results out in Python before you put them into your DB. `get_hot` and `get_new` return generator objects, so you can use a list comprehension like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import praw

# assuming you run this script every hour
an_hour_ago = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='soc')
submissions = r.get_subreddit('soccer').get_new()
submissions_list = [
    # iterate through the submissions generator object
    x for x in submissions
    # add item if item.created_utc is newer than an hour ago
    if datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.created_utc) >= an_hour_ago
]
```

By default Reddit only returns 25 listings, so if you need more than that, you'll have to paginate it.

```
limit = 100  # Reddit maximum limit
total_list = []
submissions = r.get_subreddit('soccer').get_new(limit=limit)
submissions_list = [
    x for x in submissions
    if datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.created_utc) >= an_hour_ago
]
total_list += submissions_list
if len(submissions_list) == limit:
    submissions = r.get_subreddit('soccer').get_new(
        # get limit of items past the last item in the total list
        limit=100, params={"after": total_list[-1].fullname}
    )
submissions_list_2 = [
    # iterate through the submissions generator object
    x for x in submissions
    # add item if item.created_utc is newer than an hour ago
    if datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.created_utc) >= an_hour_ago
]
total_list += submissions_list_2
print total_list
```

If the amount of submissions is greater than 200, you'll have to put that in a recursive function like this: [subreddit_latest.py](https://gist.github.com/dangayle/4e6864300b58fee09ce1)

Comment: I just mentioned that string to show as an example what I'm set out to achieve. Anyways - so are you saying that there is no way for me to get only those results which have a created_utc > x?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, no.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the API might be able to do it, it a roundabout way. You can pass in an `after` object, which would be the last post you saved your last run. It should return listings after that post. Don't know how that works in PRAW though, it doesn't look like it supports that.

Comment: @90abyss I updated the answer to integrate my last comment, the gist I attached works as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Really appreciate you spending your time on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare datetime objects not strings so you should convert them to datetime like this :

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('2016-02-18 14:33:14.000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

you should do same for created_utc too and then compare both. I don't know you can compare in get_hot function because I never used that.